# How to create timer for doing canvas rendering

Tags: android, canvas, timer

```
public void BetTimerFuction()
    {
        int delay=0;
        int period=200;
        betTimer = new Timer();
        betTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mHandlerBet.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();

            }
        }, delay, period);

    }
```

Its my timer code but i didn't work with that timer in view class i m also using canvas .
When I use that timer in view class that timer get a number prosess is very slow when i click the button its increase the the integer two timers

Comment: use View.postDelayed(Runnable);

Comment: can't get you please elaborate

Comment: @Mera When i use the background image then the timer processing is very slow like when i click 1 time on button then its response increasing the number 1 to 3 . means diffrence betwen 2 numbers

Comment: @triode its not working

Comment: post the full activity code

Comment: @Mera View class or active class

Comment: @triode please send ur mail id

Comment: @mera u also send ur mail id i send u my view class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u do the null first for your stop function.

```
public void StopBetTimer()
     {
            try
            {
                if(betTimer !=null)
                {
                    betTimer.cancel();
                    betTimer=null;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I revised you code because i think in that code no issue. But may be you didn't initialize properly to null your timer when you use first and also stop properly.

```
public void BetTimerFuction()
    {
        int delay=0;
        int period=100;
        betTimer = new Timer();
        betTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mHandlerBet.obtainMessage().sendToTarget();

            }
        }, delay, period);

    }
```

Here is for you stop function

```
public void StopBetTimer()
     {
            try
            {
                if(betTimer !=null)
                {
                    betTimer.cancel();
                    betTimer=null;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i did it a long time i dont know